# I am checking if a field is empty in an HTML form, but only the first 'if' statement is executed and then it refreshes the page

Tags: javascript

Only the first "`if`" statement is executed for `firstName`, not the second "`if`" statement for `lastName` and no alert for the error message - just refreshes the page.

```
function checkformGiftVoucher() {
    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('firstName').value == "") {     
        errormessage += "First name \n";
        document.getElementById('firstName').style.borderColor = "red";
     }
    if (document.getElementById('lastName').value == "") {
        errormessage += "Last name \n";
        document.getElementByName('lastName').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (errormessage != ""){        
      alert("Please complete the following fields: \n" + errormessage);
      return false;
    }
    else {
      /*submit*/
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your html too?

Comment: probably because condition don't match . add `console.log(document.getElementById('lastName').value);` inside function and check the console.what is the output ?

Comment: How `checkformGiftVoucher` is called? `e.preventDefault()` should be used to prevent form submission.

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

this code prevent refresh page.

and for display the error message and submit you must use this code:

```
function checkformGiftVoucher() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var errormessage = "";
    var flag = true;

    if (document.getElementById('firstName').value == "") {
        errormessage += "First name \n";
        document.getElementById('firstName').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('lastName').value == "") {
        errormessage += "Last name \n";
        document.getElementByName('lastName').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (errormessage != ""){
        flag = false
        alert("Please complete the following fields: \n" + errormessage);
    }

    if(flag == true) {
        /*submit*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
document.getElementById('lastName').style.borderColor = "red";
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementByName('lastName').style.borderColor = "red";
```